# Caching using dictionaries in a factory class

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

In my WPF application, I'm using a third party library to fetch objects which I want to allow the user to interact with.

The objects are returned as interface types and I have created wrapper classes for them. I've also created a Factory class to instantiate the wrapper classes.
Inside the factory class, I am caching the wrapper objects using dictionaries for each of the different wrapper types.

Is the use of the dictionary for caching these wrapper objects a good approach to take? Are there any obvious problems here?

```
public interface ICustomer // 3rd party Interface
{
    string Name {get; }
    string Address {get }

    // etc
}

public class ClientCustomer : IClientCustomer // Wrapper class
{
     ICustomer customer;
     public ClientCustomer(ICustomer cust)
     {
       this.customer = cust;
     }

     public string Name
     {
        get
        {
           return customer.Name;
        }
     }

    // etc
}

public class VmFactory
{
   private Dictionary<int, IClientCustomer> clientCustomers = 
        new Dictionary<int, IClientCustomer>();

    public IClientCustomer GetCustomerWrapper(ICustomer cust)
    {
       IClientCustomer clientCustomer;

       if (!clientCustomers.ContainsKey(cust.ID))
        {
            clientCustomer = new ClientCustomer(cust);
            clientCustomers.Add(cust.ID, clientCustomer);
        }
        else
        {
            clientCustomer = clientCustomers[cust.ID];
        }

          return clientCustomer;
   }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about reviewing working code. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What do you expect from caching? Is the creation of wrappers expensive enough?

Comment: @Dennis Yes some of the wrapper objects are expensive to instatiate - the caching was put in as a performance fix

Comment: @CodeCaster: why codereview does not appear as a migration site in the close request?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia because of various reasons, one of them being that it's a beta site.

Comment: @CodeCaster meh. This question would probably get closed on codereview, because the code presented has too much context stripped from it. Please don't recommed other sites when you're not 100% sure the question is on-topic.

Comment: @Vogel I'm not suggesting migration. The question certainly can't be reposted "as-is".

Comment: @CodeCaster incredibly many users are not aware of these things. In such cases it's preferrable to **explicitly** state "this cannot be reposted as-is". Many users (especially new users) interpret "Try ..." or "Have a look at ..." as: "Take this and put it to ... without changing anything". I didn't say you were suggesting migration, btw....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes you can use a Dictionary for caching but you need to consider thread safety, cache expiration, invalidation etc. I will propose alternate solutions further down.

Like @Coastpear has already pointed out, the way you're using it is no good as your Dictionary is declared as an instance variable. It needs to have a static instance in order to cache across multiple instances of the factory. If you're application is multithreaded, you'll also need to synchronize access to it in order to be thread-safe. Note: if you only have one instance of your factory for the lifetime of you app, the Dictionary don't have to be static, but you would still need to synchronize access to it if you're accessing it from multiple threads.

So, rather than using a Dictionary, I would suggest using a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Access to the dictionary is inherently thread-safe (you'll only have to worry about its contents)

```
public class VmFactory
{
   private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, IClientCustomer> clientCustomers = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IClientCustomer>();

    public IClientCustomer GetCustomerWrapper(ICustomer cust)
    {
       IClientCustomer clientCustomer;

       if (!clientCustomers.ContainsKey(cust.ID))
        {
            clientCustomer = new ClientCustomer(cust);
            clientCustomers.TryAdd(cust.ID, clientCustomer);
        }
        else
        {
            clientCustomer = clientCustomers[cust.ID];
        }

          return clientCustomer;
   }
}
```

Also have a look at [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) as another alternative, although I think ConcurrentDictionary would suffice for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Singleton with double if verification (for multithreading environments) in the VmFactory to ensure that you only have one instance of the dictionary because every time you create an instance of VmFactory you also create a new instance of the dictionary.

Comment: The less singletons the better. Why would you need to have more than one factory?

Comment: With a factory (a assume @IgnacioSolerGarcia are talking about the factory pattern) you create multiple instances of objects and in this case If the goal is make sure that only one customer ID exists then a singleton on clientCustomers is a good approach.

Comment: His class is called VmFactory so having more than one instance of it seems non needed. If you need it in several places just pass the reference around.

Comment: I won't need more than one instance of the factory, I'm using a DI container so I'll set this up to ensure that the same reference is passed into where it's needed. Thanks for your help