# Get Previously Instantiated Object from Heap for Variable Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, object, recursion

I have 2 classes that contain a class property for the other.

```
public class Client
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public Client()
    {

    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public Customer(int id)
    {
        // some retrieval logic by using id ...
    }
}
```

Here is a Factory class that shows the concept I am trying to achieve if I knew the objects prior to compile time. In reality, I do not and have to instantiate them via reflection from user provided data. Now with this in mind, I am looking to assign the object's property for the opposite class to the previously created object for that other class (i.e. like below)

```
public class Factory
{
    public Factory()
    {
        // this is all done via reflection at run-time in my real code
        Client client = new Client();
        client.Customer = new Customer(1); // id would be retrieve from a client property (not shown for simplicity sake)
        client.Customer.Client = client; // refer to the first object of client
    }
}
```

However, utilizing the previously provided factory class example, the client object in my code is not in scope or rather is higher on the stack (the various properties are instantiated recursively and if the higher class has a property with the same type in a sub-subsequent class / object it is skipped (to avoid infinite recursion).

How can I utilize either the class name or any object's properties in the factory method to point a property to a previously instantiated object when it may not be in scope?

I am thinking of using a list / dictionary to store the higher level object(s) reference and pass them down through recursion and checking if the object's type matches a sub-subsequent property's type and then just using the object stored in the list / dictionary for that property. I wanted to see if this was the best way or if there is another.

This is purely theoretical and may or may not be used. The goal is that any time and object is created from these classes, that all of the related classes have properties in the first object that contain instantiated instances of the related classes that are never null / do not infinitely recuse.

Comment: The answer is in the question.

Comment: @Guillaume Thank you, I know, but I just wanted to know if that was the best way or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a factory for both `Customer` and `Client`, with one small enhancement: You will want to use a factory that implements caching. An example can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645844/caching-using-dictionaries-in-a-factory-class#answer-29647237).

When you construct a `Customer`, just populate the `Client` from the caching factory. And vice versa. The caching mechanism will take care of the rest. Naturally you'll want the factory to be injected as a singleton instance so that the cache is common across all code that uses the factory.

The customer factory might look a little like this:

```
public class CustomerFactory : ICustomerFactory
{
    private readonly IClientFactory clientFactory;  //To be injected

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, ICustomer> customers = 
                 new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ICustomer>();

    public CustomerFactory(IClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        this.clientFactory = clientFactory; //Injected
    }

    public ICustomer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        ICustomer customer = this.customers.GetOrAdd(id, () => new Customer(id));
        if (customer.Client == null)
        {
            customer.Client = this.clientFactory.GetClient(customer.ClientID);
        }
        return customer;
    }
}
```

In the above example, you'll notice that the newly instantiated Customer is added to the cache *before* attempting to set the Client property. This is very important to avoid infinite loops. If you tried to retrieve the Client before the Customer is in the cache, the ClientFactory wouldn't be able to find it, and may end up creating a new instance.

On the other hand, maybe you don't need to set the Client property right away. After all, you have a caching mechanism now, so you can afford to set it lazily. We could remove the code from `GetCustomer`...

```
    public ICustomer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return this.customers.GetOrAdd(id, () => new Customer(id));
    }
```

...and retrieve the Client only when needed.

```
class Customer
{
   public Client Client
   {
       get
       {
           return this.clientFactory.GetClient(this.ClientID);
       }
   }
}
```

While it seems expensive to call the ClientFactory over and over, all that happens is a quick lookup in a dictionary. And if the caller doesn't even need the Client we are saving a round trip to the database.

This whole idea isn't much different from the idea that you proposed toward the end of your question, except you won't need to pass any references down. The only reference needed is a reference to the factories.

Comment: I love your ideas, however (and this is because I did not reference this in my original question), the way I have my factories setup is via a generic factory (i.e. Factory<T>) and an implementation of that factory initializes a single class + sub classes. The generic factory 'reflects' the properties and checks for a specific interface (upon which the classes are based) and then creates instances of the generic factory on the fly passing the reflected property's type as the generic type. So, all the factory's instantiations are done on the fly by creating factories from the generic on the fly.

Comment: You have me curious. How do you reflect a property's type and then pass it as the generic type? The diamond operator doesn't accept runtime variables, ie. you can't go `var o = new GenericType<someVariable>`

Comment: The .NET Reflection framework is the key. You use MakeGenericType method from the type of the generic class you want to instantiate then GetMethod for the method, then Activator.CreateInstance(passing the MakeGenericType type result, your constructor params [if any]). It works VERY well for me, but there are optimizations out there for activator, but I have not investigated them thoroughly. It is not done in compile time, but I do not mind the trade off of cleaner, leaner, and more robust code by sacrificing a small amount of compile time (AKA Intellisense) knowledge in a single method / class